JPA/Hibernate approach to field with interface behavior
I have an existing system with the below (simplified) entities and I would like to add a new Set<ReportableCost> property to Journal. It's important that I be able to start with a ReportableCost and access properties of the parent, a reference (voucherId/journaldId) and date (accountingDate/journalDate). Is there a way to create this new mapping, ideally by adding a new column to the ReportableCost table indicating with which type the parent_id is associated? I know that the existing FK dependency will need to be removed to make that possible.
@Data
@Entity
public class Voucher {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "voucher_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "voucher_id_seq", sequenceName = "voucher_id_seq", allocationSize = 10)
    private Long id;
        
    private String voucherId;
    private LocalDate accountingDate;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="voucher", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<VoucherLine> lines;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<ReportableCost> costList;

}

@Data
@Entity
public class ReportableCost {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cost_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "cost_id_seq", sequenceName = "cost_id_seq", allocationSize = 10)
    private Long id;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable=false, foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name="Fk_voucher_cost"))
    private Voucher parent;
    
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private String description;
    private boolean processed=false;
}

@Data
@Entity
public class Journal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "journal_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "journal_id_seq", sequenceName = "journal_id_seq", allocationSize = 10)
    private Long id;
    
    private String journalId;
    private LocalDate journalDate;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="journal", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<JournalLine> lines;
}


Without JPA this approach would suggest creating an interface/abstract class, updating the Voucher reference to a ReportableCost, then implementing the required methods Voucher and Journal.
However, JPA doesn't seem to allow interfaces in mapped associations (since they don't carry and @Entity annotation) and using @MappedSuperClass or @Inheritance requires that the @Id column be placed into the super class instead of the individual concrete classes (not possible since these use separate sequences). @DiscriminatorColumn/@DiscriminatorValue don't seem like they would work either since they're used for mapping multiple entities to a single table.
